# Как реализована 2D физика в box2d и подобных движках?

Tags: javascript, 2d, физика, движок

Привет.

Минимально знаком с методом Верле, писал на js свои велосипеды,
но макс до куда дошёл - столкновение псевдо-твёрдых тел с поверхностью.

Хочу сделать столкновение динамических N объектов, в частности прямоугольников на узлы которых действуют свои силы.

Что есть (что умею): https://linkabox.ru/tojsfiddle.html (хватать за узлы и кидать) (также есть фидлы с верёвкой и тканью) (сервис не даёт вставлять ссылки на jsfiddle без кода, но код тут не имеет никакого значения)

Цель: https://phaser.io/examples/v2/box2d/mouse-drag#plugin

Проблема: старые статьи которые читал закончились, нужного уровня не достиг.

Вопрос: Как такая физика реализована в фазере в box2d и подобных физических движках, не претендующих на точность, лишь на визуальную достоверность? Методы, способы, может что посоветуете почитать? (очень желательно на русском)

По просьбе интересующегося даю ссылку на материалы, по которым делал что есть: http://flasher.ru/forum/blog.php?b=182

Comment: +1, тоже интересует тема. Сам несколько книг видел по теме, читал. Если найду, скину их сюда

Comment: Да, Антон, будьте добры привести источники, что читали. Может пригодиться.